# Blender - displacement of a repeated mesh over another single mesh

Tags: blender

My idea is to achieve something similar to this:

[image: Example image]

Let's say that I have 2 mesh:

- 1 cube
- 1 character

I want to cover all the body part of my character or a particular region with this cube duplicated as much as is necessary: how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

To make an image like that would take a lot of time. Your best friend in Blender to create this image is going to be `shift+D`. Select all the vertices in your box mesh, press `shift+D` to make a duplicate of the mesh, then move it to its new position.

You could try to use some modifiers to repeat the mesh along the axes, but then you'd still have to go over each and every box mesh to move them slightly to the position.

After this, you'll need to map a texture/material to them. It's most likely a material as they look pretty solid color and almost "not shiny plastic" looking.

Then you'll probably want to setup the lights to shine on the main "character" (looks to me like there's one big spotlight shining on it) then play with its settings to get the right feel of the render.

Render your image.

You can then in Photoshop add the colors to them with a layer over the top of your renderes image to add color, also during this step you can add more shadows and other effects if the mood takes you.

But I think you're going to become best friends with `shift+D` over the next few days! I wish you luck, this doesn't look like a quick/easy image to make. Have fun :)

Answer (score 2):

greeble is a very very good hint. I used it in Blender 2.4.

The plugin I used was the "Discombobulator"

http://www.nccn.net/~w_rosky/evan/evan/programs/discombobulator/index.html

Had no need for such an effect in quite a while, so I don't know if the plugin works in the current version of Blender. But: it's easy to create an model in an older version of Blender (which are all easy to get) and import it in a newer version, that building such an effect from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow this reminds me of a technique called [greeble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeble). [Here is a quick tutorial](http://thithimimi.deviantart.com/art/blender-greeble-tutorial-169649289) on how to achieve this with blender.
Another possible solution is to write a python script to do this (or even search for one, there could already exist one).